# How to use internal storage android?

Tags: android

I have a file : language.txt which is in internal storage. I tried reading that file as a string and check this string to choose values from database. I really can't understand why it's not working. **DBDAO** class is a class managing **databasehelpers**.

This is my code:

```
public class DBDAO {
    protected SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private DataBaseHelper_FR dbHelper_FR;
    private Context mContext;
public DBDAO(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        open();
    }

public void open() throws SQLException {

        if(fileExists(mContext, "language.txt"))
        {
            lang = main.ReadFile();
        }
        else
        {
            main.WriteFile("English");
            lang = "English";
        }
        if (lang == "English") {
            if (dbHelper == null)
                dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        else if (lang == "France") {
            if (dbHelper_FR == null)
                dbHelper_FR = new DataBaseHelper_FR(mContext);
            database = dbHelper_FR.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }
    public boolean fileExists(Context context, String filename) {
        File file = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
        if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // write text to file
        public void WriteFile(String writeString) {
            // add-write text into file
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileout = mContext.openFileOutput("language.txt", mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
                OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
                outputWriter.write(writeString);
                outputWriter.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Read text from file
        public String ReadFile() {
            // reading text from file
            String s = "";
            try {
                FileInputStream fileIn = mContext.openFileInput("language.txt");
                InputStreamReader InputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[100];
                int charRead;
                while ((charRead = InputRead.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                    // char to string conversion
                    String readstring = String
                            .copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                    s += readstring;
                }
                InputRead.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return s;
        }
}
```

and results:

```
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{us.datn_02/us.datn_02.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at us.datn_02.db.CauHoiDAO.getTenChuDe(CauHoiDAO.java:257)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at us.datn_02.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
04-28 00:16:31.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     ... 11 more
```

Is something wrong?
Can Some one help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what is happening? What do you mean by "it's not working"? Are you getting an error? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: What is line no. 257 & 57?

Comment: It's return null @VVB. Because can not get `lang`, `if (lang == "English")` and `if (lang == "France")` not run. So line no.257 and 57 return null.

Comment: AFAIU It goes inside  if(fileExists(mContext, "language.txt"))
        {
            lang = main.ReadFile();
        } this block, there it is unable to fetch lang & that's why your getting java.lang.NullPointerException. Try to set static value & then check it.

Comment: your mean is set `lang` to static value in DBDAO class? @VVB

Comment: It's still error @VVB

Comment: Pass this inside it lang = "English";

Comment: It's not change. still not work. thank you so much @VVB

Comment: what is the result of `lang = main.ReadFile();` in your `if(fileExists(...))` statement? It sounds like that is returning `lang = null` which is carried through to the rest of your activity.

Comment: Your checks `if(lang == "xxx")` should be `if(lang != null && "xxx".equals(lang))` as well rather than trying to do an `==` operator on a potential null.